# What do you call the act of commenting about a sports game?

Tags: word-request

I know the related term color-commentating, but color-commentating isn't sports talk, there's one guy commenting about the sports game and the other just make it more colorful by not specifically talking about the game, but what's the verb for sports-commenting?

> The host was sports-commenting about today's football game live.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean the partner of a **play-by-play announcer** who chimes in from time to time, or a person who talks about sports news to a TV camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

commentating.

An example of the word being used is shown below:

Joe was commentating on the game, when all of a sudden, the stadium lights turned off.

Answer (score 1):

**commentary** noun [ C or U ]

a spoken description of an event on the radio or television that is broadcast as the event happens:

---

**commentate** verb [ I ]

to provide a spoken description of and remarks on an event, especially a sports competition, as it happens:

Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/commentate)